# Maven gives MojoFailureException even though ANT build gives no error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I am using ANT in eclipse clean+Build, it doesn't give me any error/problems.

However when I build using Maven it gives following error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TFMWithSpark 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TFMWithSpark ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TFMWithSpark ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to C:\Users\asoza\SparkWorkspace\TFMWithSpark\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java: C:\Users\asoza\SparkWorkspace\TFMWithSpark\src\main\java\com\tfmwithspark\SparkVMACache.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[8,36] package com.splwg.base.api.datatypes does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[9,74] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[10,74] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[11,74] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[41,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Bool
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeServiceQuantityDetailVO.java:[6,32] package com.splwg.ccb.api.lookup does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[47,18] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeLineDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[48,18] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeCharacteristicDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[352,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Bool
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[359,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Bool
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[422,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeLineDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[429,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeLineDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[436,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeCharacteristicDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkBillableChargeDetailVO.java:[443,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BillableChargeCharacteristicDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkBillableChargeDetailVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[22,25] package org.hibernate.cfg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[23,30] package org.hibernate.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[25,34] package com.splwg.base.api.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[26,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[27,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[28,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[29,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[30,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[31,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[32,33] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.util does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[33,31] package com.splwg.shared.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[34,31] package com.splwg.shared.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[35,32] package com.splwg.shared.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[36,32] package com.splwg.shared.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[37,32] package com.splwg.shared.environ does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestView.java:[76,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class FrameworkSession
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.TestView
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[7,74] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[68,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[90,29] package com.ibm.icu.math does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[629,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[636,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ErrorDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[777,28] package com.ibm.icu.math does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkTransactionPriceItemDetailSummaryVO.java:[784,47] package com.ibm.icu.math does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[24,36] package com.splwg.base.api.datatypes does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[25,57] package com.splwg.base.domain.common.featureConfiguration does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[26,57] package com.splwg.base.domain.common.featureConfiguration does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[27,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[28,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[29,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[30,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[31,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[32,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[33,71] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[34,74] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.banking.transactionFeed.transactionFeedAgg.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[35,51] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceassign.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[36,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[37,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[38,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[39,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[40,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceparm does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[41,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceparm does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[42,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceparm does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[130,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EffectiveDatedProductParameterDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[132,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PriceParm
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[149,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TransactionRecordTypeVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[151,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DivisionCharacteristicDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[154,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SQIFragmentDetails
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[157,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AlgoParmVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[159,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DivisionDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[161,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SchedulePeriodData
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[297,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TransactionRecordTypeVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[313,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DivisionCharacteristicDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[329,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SQIFragmentDetails
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[345,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SchedulePeriodData
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[350,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PriceParm
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[651,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EffectiveDatedProductParameterDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1270,102] package com.splwg.base.api.datatypes does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1317,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DivisionDetailVO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1618,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PriceItemParm_DTO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1626,18] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PriceItemParm_DTO
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1646,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EffectiveDatedProductParameterDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkVMACache.java:[1645,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EffectiveDatedProductParameterDetail
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkVMACache
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/BillableChargeAndSQSparkVO.java:[7,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[22,30] package org.hibernate.internal does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[25,34] package com.splwg.base.api.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[26,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[27,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[28,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[29,38] package com.splwg.base.support.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[30,33] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.util does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[31,32] package com.splwg.shared.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[32,32] package com.splwg.shared.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[33,32] package com.splwg.shared.environ does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/TestMaterializedView.java:[68,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class FrameworkSession
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.TestMaterializedView
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[7,36] package com.splwg.base.api.datatypes does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[8,36] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[9,54] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceassign.enums does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[10,54] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceassign.enums does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[11,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceitem does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[12,46] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.priceparm does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[13,47] package com.splwg.ccb.domain.pricing.service.vo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[64,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkPriceAsgnVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[66,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkPriceAsgnVO
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asoza/SparkWorkspace/TFMWithSpark/src/main/java/com/tfmwithspark/SparkPriceAsgnVO.java:[68,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class com.tfmwithspark.SparkPriceAsgnVO

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I already checked solutions which asks to check if Java version is correctly mentioned in pom.xml.

I have checked it in my pom.xml and it is correct.

I am not able to understand why this error is occuring.

below my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tfmwithspark</groupId>
    <artifactId>TFMWithSpark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I am using **Maven - 3.5.3** and **java version "1.8.0_211"**

Comment: first you have missing dependencies because of this: `package com.splwg.base.api.datatypes does not exist`  ...

Comment: @khmarbaise those jars are added in build path.

Comment: @khmarbaise and are also present under Maven dependencies

Comment: You haven't declared them within your pom. That's the only way to go...

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all dependencies in your POM.

I guess that packages starting with `com.splwg` are neither part of your project nor belongs to Spark.

Those dependency must be someway declared in your POM.

If those jar are not in a public maven repository you either *install* them locally, or *deploy* in a private maven repository or (and if neither is possible) reference them with the `systemPath` property of the dependecy.

You should check maven [guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

The only **dirty hack** which is quick enough to include in this answer is the system path dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>local.hack</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.splwg.base</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <!-- here you set the local machine path of your jar -->
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/splwg_base_jar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I would not recommend this approach, but my guess is that you are already using local dependencies in your project, so importing them in maven does not introduce any problem.

Sharing a POM with local dependency with other developers is not a good idea, and you should go for a *private maven repository*.

A *private maven repository* is just a dedicated webapp which let you *upload* jars as maven artifact which then you can include as dependencies in your pom.

It has also the benefit (if you want) to proxy maven repository so you get a local network cache of maven artifact you use.

There are several local artifact repository software like NEXUS or Artifactory, pick one and follow its guide.

Comment: Those jars I have placed physically and included in my build path. Earlier same maven build was working but now it is not working.I am not able to find what is the issue

Comment: Build path is good enough for running in an IDE (like eclipse) but is not enough for maven. So when you `clean build` your project it will fail to compile. If you use maven you __must__ declare dependencies.